# splice() on std::list and iterator invalidation

Tags: c++, list, containers, iterator

The 3-argument form of `list::splice()` moves a single element from one list to the other.  [SGI's documentation](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/init.cgi) explicitly states that all iterators, *including the one pointing to the element being moved* remain valid.  [Roguewave's documentation](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/) does not say anything about iterator invalidation properties of `splice()` methods, whereas the C++ standard explicitly states that it invalidates all iterators and references to the element being spliced.

splicing() in practice works as defined by SGI, but I get assertion failure (dereferencing invalid iterator) in debug / secure SCL versions of microsoft's STL implementation (which strictly follows the letter of the standard).

Now, I'm using list exactly because I want to move an element between lists, while preserving the validity of the iterator pointing to it.  The standard has made an extremely unhelpful change to the original SGI's specification.

How can I work around this problem?  Or should I just be pragmatic and stick my head in the sand (because the splicing does **not** invalidate iterators in practice -- not even in the MS's implementation, once iterator debugging is turned off).

Comment: Great question. What was the final word ?

Comment: The standard is stupid, but right. Don't use splice in standards-conforming programs. Maybe C++1x amended the situation; I have not checked.

Comment: I just checked, it does change. The wording retained is the one of the LWG defect 250: the old iterators are valid, and behave as if they are pointing to the new container.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, this seems to be a defect in the standard, according to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#250) and [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#278) link.  It seems that "sticking the head in the sand" is a good strategy, since it will be fixed in new library versions.

Comment: It still has not :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if the iterator still points to the element that was moved, then the "end" iterator previously associated with the "moved" iterator has changed.  Unless you write some complex loop, this is actually a bad thing to do -- especially since it will be more difficult for other developers to understand.

A better way in my opinion is to use the iterators pointing to the elements prior and after the moved iterator.

Comment: Depends on whether he keeps iterators around to access the elements without losing the list manipulation ability or whether he is currently iterating over the list, in which case he will indeed have to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I have an array of lists (equivalence classes of elements), and I'm using splice to move elements between the lists.  I have an additional array of iterators which gives me direct access to any element in any of the lists and to move it to another list.  None of the lists is searched and modified at the same time.  I *could* reinitialize the element iterator after splice, but it's kinda ugly..  I guess I'll do that for the time being.