# Refactoring advice: How to avoid type checking in this OO design

Tags: c++, object, refactoring, type-conversion, dynamic-cast

I'm looking for advice on refactoring to improve my class design and avoid type checking.

I am using the Command design pattern to construct a menu tree. An item in the menu could be of various types (e.g., an immediate action [like "Save"], a toggle on/off property which displays with check/icon depending on its state [like "italics"], etc.). Crucially, there are also submenus, which *replace* (rather than displaying off to the side of) the current menu on the screen. These submenus of course contain their own list of menu items, which could have more nested submenus.

The code is something like (all public for simplicity in presentation):

```
// Abstract base class
struct MenuItem
{
  virtual ~MenuItem() {}
  virtual void Execute()      = 0;
  virtual bool IsMenu() const = 0;
};

// Concrete classes
struct Action : MenuItem
{
  void Execute() { /*...*/ }
  bool IsMenu() const { return false; }
  // ...
};

// ... other menu items

struct Menu : MenuItem
{
  void Execute() { /* Display menu */ }
  bool IsMenu() const { return true; }
  // ...
  std::vector<MenuItem*> m_items;
  typedef std::vector<MenuItem*>::iterator ItemIter;
};
```

The main menu is just an instance of Menu, and a separate class keeps track of the menu position, including how to go into and out of submenus:

```
struct Position
{
  Position( Menu* menu ) 
    : m_menu( menu ) 
  {
    // Save initial position
    m_pos.push_back( MenuPlusIter( m_menu, m_menu->m_items.begin() ) );
  }

  // Ignore error conditions for simplicity
  void OnUpPressed()   { m_pos.back().iter--; }
  void OnDownPressed() { m_pos.back().iter++; }
  void OnBackPressed() { m_pos.pop_back();    }

  void OnEnterPressed()
  {
    MenuItem* item = *m_pos.back().iter;
    // Need to behave differently here if the currently 
    // selected item is a submenu
    if( item->IsMenu() )
    {
      // dynamic_cast not needed since we know the type
      Menu* submenu = static_cast<Menu*>( item );

      // Push new menu and position onto the stack
      m_pos.push_back( MenuPlusIter( submenu, submenu->m_items.begin() ) );

      // Redraw
      submenu->Execute();
    }
    else
    {
      item->Execute();
    }
  }

private:
  struct MenuPlusIter
  {
      Menu*          menu;
      Menu::ItemIter iter;

      MenuPlusIter( Menu* menu_, Menu::ItemIter iter_ )
          : menu( menu_ )
          , iter( iter_ )
      {}
  };

  Menu* m_menu;
  std::vector<MenuPlusIter> m_pos;
};
```

The key function is Position::OnEnterPressed(), where you see an explicit type check in the call to MenuItem::IsMenu() and then a cast to the derived type. What are some options to refactor this to avoid the type check and cast?

Comment: I don't see the problem with the cast. Actually, I fail to see a smart way to remove it without cluttering the code. After all, you *do* want something different to happen when you encounter a submenu, don't you ? Hell, I'd even go with `dynamic_cast` and remove this `IsMenu` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, the refactoring starting point would be these statements:

```
 1. m_pos.push_back( MenuPlusIter( m_menu, m_menu->m_items.begin() ) );

 2. m_pos.push_back( MenuPlusIter( submenu, submenu->m_items.begin() ) );
```

The fact that the same kind of statement repeat itself is, IMO, the sign for the need to refactor that.

If you could factor (1) in a method of your base class, and then override it in the derived class to take into account the specific behavior (2), then you could just put this in `Execute`.

Correct me if I am wrong: the idea is the a menu has items, and each item has got an action associated to it that is triggered when some event is detected.

Now, when the item you select is a submenu, the the `Execute` action has the meaning: activate the submenu (I am using activate in a generic sense). When the item is not a submenu, then `Execute` is a different beast.

I don't have a full comprehension of your menu system, but it seems to me you have a sort of hierarchy menu/submenu (the positions), and some actions that are triggered depending of the kind of node.

What I envision is that the menu/submenu relationship is a hierarchy that allows you to define leaf-nodes (when you don't have a submenu), and non-leaf-nodes (the submenu). A leaf node invoke an action, a non-leaf-node invoke a different kind of action which deals with activating a submenu (this action goes back to the menu system, so you do not encapsulate knowledge about the menu system in it, you simply relay the action to menu system).

Don't know if this makes sense to you.

Comment: In your last paragraph, do you mean add something like void UpdateMenu(vector<MenuPlusIter>&) to the MenuItem base class, which does nothing in all but one derived class (Menu)? If so, that seems to me like it decreases the "single responsibility" principle by moving menu navigation logic out of the pointer-esque Position class and into the pointee classes themselves. The blank override for all but one class also seems like an alternate "abuse" of an inheritance hierarchy from the one that I'll be accused of with my current implementation or one that uses dynamic_cast.

Comment: Your update makes sense. It still seems like it's choosing between two non-ideal options, so I'll have to think about it more. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You are welcome! You know, many times there is no thing like a perfect solution...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to expose a method in Position which enables a Menu to be pushed onto the stack, and call that method at the start of Menu:Execute. Then the body of OnEnterPressed just becomes

```
(*m_pos.back().iter)->Execute();
```

Comment: That seems to add tighter (two-way) coupling between the classes, and since that method would be empty for all the concrete MenuItems except Menu, it seems like that's just an alternate abuse of an inheritance hierarchy. Is there some reason to prefer your abuse over mine?

Comment: I am not suggesting a new method in MenuItem, but a new method in Position. Admittedly that means MenuItem now has to have access to Position. I'm just suggesting it as an alternative, not claiming it is better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the response you were looking for, but in my opinion your solution is by far superior to any solution that doesn't involve type checking.

Most C++ programmers are offended by the idea that you need to check an object's type in order to decide what to do with it. Yet in other languages like Objective-C and most weakly typed script languages this is actually highly encouraged.

In your case I think using the type check is well chosen since you need the type information for the functionality of `Position`. Moving this functionality into one of the `MenuItem` subclasses would IMHO violate competence separation. `Position` is concerned with the viewing and controller part of your menu. I don't see why the model classes `Menu` or `MenuItem` should be concerned with that. Moving to a no-typecheck solution would decrease code quality in terms of object orientation.

Comment: I do agree. I'd take this even further and advocate using `dynamic_cast` here, and get rid of `IsMenu`. Be prepared to defend it against coding standard nazis during code reviews however.

Comment: I have often seen the claim that dynamic_cast (or equivalents, as here) is an indication of flawed design, and most of the time that's correct, I think. But here, I'm having trouble coming up with a more satisfactory solution.

Comment: @mlimber: You'll find in practice that `dynamic_cast` is ok if you have a single (or perhaps two) subhierarchies which deserve particular treatment. It is in all cases always better than a flag and `static_cast`. The OO paradigm isn't always the best. In functional languages, pattern matching is commonplace, and directly transcribed in OOP, it gives downcasting, multiple dispatch and the ugly visitor pattern. I definitely prefer throwing one or two well placed dynamic casts rather than set up a visitor pattern (if no *simpler* solution exists of course).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the ability to express "either an action or a menu", which is very cumbersome to write using polymorphism if actions and menus have very different interfaces.

Instead of trying to force them into a common interface (`Execute` is a poor name for the submenu method), I'd go further than you and use `dynamic_cast`.

Also, `dynamic_cast` is *always* superior to a flag and `static_cast`. Actions do not neet to tell the world that they aren't submenus.

Rewritten in the most idiomatic C++, this gives the following code. I use `std::list` because of its convenience methods `splice`, `insert` and `remove` which don't invalidate iterators (one of the few good reasons for using linked lists). I also use `std::stack` for keeping track of the open menus.

```
struct menu_item
{
    virtual ~menu_item() {}

    virtual std::string label() = 0;
    ...
};

struct action : menu_item
{
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

struct submenu : menu_item
{
    // You should go virtual here, and get rid of the items member.
    // This enables dynamically generated menus, and nothing prevents
    // you from having a single static_submenu class which holds a 
    // vector or a list of menu_items.
    virtual std::list<menu_item*> unfold() = 0;
};

struct menu
{
    void on_up() { if (current_item != items.begin()) current_item--; }
    void on_down() { if (++current_item == items.end()) current_item--; }

    void on_enter()
    {
        if (submenu* m = dynamic_cast<submenu*>(current_item))
        {
            std::list<menu_item*> new_menu = m->unfold();

            submenu_stack.push(submenu_info(*current_item, new_menu));

            items.splice(current_item, new_menu);
            items.erase(current_item);
            current_item = submenu_stack.top().begin;

            redraw(current_item, items.end());
        }

        else if (action* a = dynamic_cast<action*>(current_item))
            a->execute();

        else throw std::logic_error("Unknown menu entry type");

        // If we were to add more else if (dynamic_cast) clauses, this
        // would mean we don't have the right design. Here we are pretty
        // sure this won't happen. This is what you say to coding standard
        // nazis who loathe RTTI.
    }

    void on_back()
    {
        if (!submenu_stack.empty())
        {
            const submenu_info& s = submenu_stack.top();

            current_item = items.insert(items.erase(s.begin, s.end), s.root);
            submenu_stack.pop();

            redraw(current_item, items.end());
        }
    }

    void redraw(std::list<menu_item*>::iterator begin, 
                std::list<menu_item*>::iterator end)
    {
       ...
    }

private:
    std::list<menu_item*> items;
    std::list<menu_item*>::iterator current_item;

    struct submenu_info
    {
        submenu* root;
        std::list<menu_item*>::iterator begin, end;

        submenu_info(submenu* root, std::list<menu_item*>& m)
            : root(root), begin(m.begin()), end(m.end())
        {}
    };

    std::stack<submenu_info> submenu_stack;
};
```

I tried to keep the code straightforward. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

*[About iterator invalidation when doing `splice`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143156/splice-on-stdlist-and-iterator-invalidation) (tl;dr: it is OK to splice and keep the old iterators provided you don't use a too old compiler).]*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed ideas! That gives me some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

The language already provides this mechanism- it's `dynamic_cast`. However, in a more general sense, the inherent flaw in your design is this:

```
m_pos.push_back( MenuPlusIter( submenu, submenu->m_items.begin() ) );
```

It should go in the Execute() function, and refactor as necessary to make that happen.

Comment: Repeating from a similar answer: Do you mean add something like void UpdateMenu(vector<MenuPlusIter>&) to the MenuItem base class, which does nothing in all but one derived class (Menu)? If so, that seems to me like it decreases the "single responsibility" principle by moving menu navigation logic out of the pointer-esque Position class and into the pointee classes themselves. The blank override for all but one class also seems like an alternate "abuse" of an inheritance hierarchy from the one that I'll be accused of with my current implementation or one that uses dynamic_cast.