# Join and re-split two std::list's without allocation

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I would like to do the following:

1. join two `std::list`s (`l1` and `l2`)
2. pass the combined list to a function
3. restore the two original lists

All this should happen without allocating new memory.

First I wanted to try this with `splice()`, but then I read that the iterators of the moved items would be invalidated by `splice()`.
Then, however, I read this SO answer: [splice() on std::list and iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143156/splice-on-stdlist-and-iterator-invalidation/143165#143165)
and decided to try it anyway:

```
iterator temp = l2.begin();
l1.splice(l1.end(), l2);
my_function(l1);
l2.splice(l2.end(), l1, temp, l1.end());
```

This works in many cases, but if `l2` is initially empty, it doesn't (because `temp` doesn't point to anything meaningful).

Of course I could check for `l2.size() > 0`, but all this seems a little too work-around-ish to me.

Does anyone know a better/cleaner solution to my initial problem?

Comment: If `my_function` is actually "your" function, you could make it take a starting and ending iterator...and then make a generalized aggregate iterator class which handled the logic of stepping across multiple collections...?

Comment: @HostileFork: thanks for your comment, I thought about this but such a fancy iterator seemed a little too much effort for my task at hand. But the real downside would be that I always would have to use the _fancy iterator_, even if I have only one simple list. I didn't mention this, but I want to be able to use `my_function()` some times with a single list and other times with a combined list, this is _not_ a compile-time decision.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not a compile-time decision", but in any case the *fancy iterator* could reduce very simply into the normal iterator in the single list case...its begin and end methods would simply return a wrapped version of the contained list's begin and end iterators if there was only one.  Pretty much no performance hit whatsoever.  You can also overload `my_function`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically I meant that `my_function` cannot be a template function. This function is called repeatedly in some worker threads and it must be the exact same function every time (no overloads). So I can have only one iterator type and this would have to be the _fancy iterator_.
Anyway, I'm sure it would work but I find the list-manipulation-thingy simpler to implement and simpler to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn the logic around to keep a valid iterator:

```
auto temp = l2.begin();

l2.splice(temp, l1);  // "L2 = L1 + L2"

my_function(l2);

l1.splice(l1.end(), l2, l2.begin(), temp);  // restores both l1 and l2
```

Comment: Wow, such a small change made all the difference! Now it works perfectly!