# std::list.splice() causes program to crash

Tags: c++, stl

I looked at a few examples and as far as I can tell I'm using the splice method correctly. However, when I run the program in debug mode under Visual C++, the call stack shows my call to splice eventually reaches this line where it crashes:

```
_Mynextiter = _Parent_proxy->_Myfirstiter;
```

The code:

```
    for(std::list<Rect>::iterator i = rects.begin(); i != rects.end();)
    {
        if(i->isOverlapping(newRect))
        {
            Rect oldRect = (*i);
            i = rects.erase(i);
            std::list<Rect> & lr = oldRect.split(newRect);
            //doesn't work either
            //rects.splice(rects.begin(), lr, lr.begin(), lr.end());
            rects.splice(rects.begin(), lr);
        }
        else i++;
    }
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143156/splice-on-stdlist-and-iterator-invalidation

Comment: OK, so it looks like the lists may not be splice-able within a loop. I made an implementation that doesn't splice within the loop, but I wasn't able to test it since I'm away from my Windows machine and I'm getting totally different behavior in g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using `std::list<T>::splice()` the right way, if I refer to any manual pages on the internet.

At the contrary, I don't really like the reference in the line:

```
std::list<Rect> & lr = oldRect.split(newRect);
```

I don't know what is doing `Rect::split()` but you should try to copy its result. Does that help?

Comment: Sure enough, I was returning a reference to an object with automatic storage duration. I fixed this, and I also moved the splicing out of the loop. This seems to have fixed the error.