# STL list::splice - iterator validity

Tags: c++, list, stl

I'm reading how "[list::splice](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/)" works and I don't understand something:

```
  mylist1.splice (it, mylist2); // mylist1: 1 10 20 30 2 3 4
                                // mylist2 (empty)
                                // "it" still points to 2 (the 5th element)

  mylist2.splice (mylist2.begin(),mylist1, it);
                                // mylist1: 1 10 20 30 3 4
                                // mylist2: 2
                                // "it" is now invalid.
  it = mylist1.begin();
  std::advance(it,3);           // "it" points now to 30

  mylist1.splice ( mylist1.begin(), mylist1, it, mylist1.end());
                                // mylist1: 30 3 4 1 10 20
```

in the first and third splice the **it** iterator is still valid, but why isn't it in the second splice?

According to the documentation:

> Iterator validity
>
> No changes on the iterators, pointers and references
>   related to the container before the call. **The iterators, pointers and
>   references that referred to transferred elements keep referring to
>   those same elements**, but iterators now iterate into the container the
>   elements have been transferred to.

thus it should still be valid

Comment: That resource is notoriously inaccurate. Take anything and everything it says with a pound of salt.

Comment: cppreference says the same: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: I don't see this on cppreference, they explicitly say that *no* iterators are invalidated by `splice`.

Comment: Where? I only see it says "No iterators or references become invalidated".

Comment: @DanielFrey the problem persists, the iterator is invalid after the second splice while cppreference states that it should remain valid

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: I edited my answer and added a reference to the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only a guess, but they might have written that to imply that `it` is now "invalid" in the sense that it is no longer a valid iterator of `mylist1`, but instead becomes a valid iterator of `mylist2`.

But still, and I guess you already knew that, it is a valid iterator, so the wording is misleading. You need to be careful, though, as it means that after the second splice-operation, for example, you can no longer do:

```
std::distance( mylist1.begin(), it );
```

but need to use

```
std::distance( mylist2.begin(), it );
```

as the first would be illegal.

The standard clearly defines it that way in:

> #### 23.3.5.5 list operations [list.ops]
>
> `void splice(const_iterator position, list& x, const_iterator i);`
> `void splice(const_iterator position, list&& x, const_iterator i);`
>
> <sup>7</sup> *Effects:* Inserts an element pointed to by `i` from list `x` before `position` and removes the element from `x`. The result is unchanged if `position == i` or `position == ++i`. Pointers and references to `*i` continue to refer to this same element but as a member of `*this`. Iterators to `*i` (including `i` itself) continue to refer to the same element, but now behave as iterators into `*this`, not into `x`.

So, if your compiler/STL invalidates the iterator, this is clearly a bug.

Comment: I agree with you, must be a MSVC bug

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (since I'm using MSVC2012) the behavior is different:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72fb8wzd.aspx

> In all cases, only iterators or references that point at spliced
>   elements become invalid.

Thus when I have iterators to elements that get moved from one container to another, these iterators become invalid.

I'd be interested in knowing if this behavior is the standard one, though.

Comment: why is the microsoft library implemented in a different way ? any sane reason ?

Comment: There's a defect in the Standard, and MSVC2012 apparently follows it to the letter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/143165/4130137